# Showing type error everytime I try to post dynamic content with javascript (code included)

Tags: javascript, post, dynamic, typeerror

```js
const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('section-center');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  
  let displayMenu = menu.map(function(item){
    
    return
     `<article class="menu-item">
       <img  src=${item.img} class="photo" alt=${item.title}>
       <div class="item-info">
         <header>
         <h4>${item.title}</h4>
         <h4 class="price">$${item.price}</h4>
         </header>
         <p class="item-text">${item.desc}</p>
       </div>
     </article>  `;
  });

  displayMenu = displayMenu.join("");
  
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
  
  
});
```

I am trying to display content on the main page dynamically. So it is very basic. Everything works the way it should until I get to last couple of lines.

The error  - "app.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

I went over the code many times and cannot seem to find a flaw. Error keep showing. Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: May you share an example of the array `menu` as well? It is not defined in the example

Comment: It sounds like `document.querySelector('section-center')` is returning `null`. This is looking for an element that is `<section-center/>`. I feel like that must be wrong? You probably want `document.querySelector('.section-center')` (query by className) or `document.querySelector('#section-center')` (query by id)

Comment: Austin Ezell I thought I checked everything. But you definitely solved the issue. I am looking for a way to give you an upvote or something like that but can't seem to find a way to do that either. Many thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @AustinEzell so it is a typo?

Comment: @qaz I'll post as an answer with the same info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `document.querySelector('section-center')` is looking for an element of `<section-center />`. I'd guess you actually want:

```
document.querySelector('.section-center') // (query by `class`) 
// or
document.querySelector('#section-center') // (query by `id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have filled in a couple gaps that I assume you have maybe?

- You need your `querySelector` to work
- You need `menu` to be defined and in the right shape
- You need to return without a new line

```js
const menu = [
  { img: 'img1', title: 'title1', price: 'price1', desc: 'desc1' },
  { img: 'img2', title: 'title2', price: 'price2', desc: 'desc2' }
];

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('#section-center');
  
  let displayMenu = menu.map(function(item) {
    return `<article class="menu-item">
       <img  src=${item.img} class="photo" alt=${item.title}>
       <div class="item-info">
         <header>
         <h4>${item.title}</h4>
         <h4 class="price">$${item.price}</h4>
         </header>
         <p class="item-text">${item.desc}</p>
       </div>
     </article>  `;
  });

  displayMenu = displayMenu.join("");
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
});
```

```html
<div id="section-center"></div>
```